# How to find infinite optimal solutions for linear program?

Tags: analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, linear-programming, operations-research

Consider $$\text{max} \  5x_1+3x_2$$ $$s.t.\ 2x_1+x_2\le 8$$ $$3x_1+2x_2\ge 6$$ $$x_1,x_2\ge0$$

Change the objective function by another function such that the resulting program has infinite optimal solutions.

---

Any hint please?

How will I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the objective function a constant and every feasible point is an optimal solution.

Remark: You still have to prove that the feasible set has infinitely many points. You might like to use convexity to prove this.

Comment: How do I make the function a constant?

Comment: Let the objective function be a constant, say $0$, $1$, or even $\pi$. That is every point is equally optimal.

Comment: $ \max 0x_1+0x_2$.

Answer (score 2):

You can visualize this very nicely, see https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jiukwzxdxt

If you change the objective function so that its contour lines are perpendicular to one of the edges of the feasible region, you also get infinitely many solutions.